# (Stock) Indexes on Import in EE

Tags: import, ee-1.13, stock, index

Why are importing (standard CSV import, not dataflow) product lists and the field is_in_stock does not seem to have an effect.

In the backend it is shown properly, but not in the frontend.

Clearing the cache does not help.

I suppose, that the problem is the `cataloginventory_stock` index, but rebuilding that one on the command line does not help though (forcing rebuilding in the backend seems no longer possible in EE 1.13)

When I save the product once again in the backend, it works.

Is this a known behavior?

*edit*
From Enterprise support I got the answer to try a full reindex - using the `indexer.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when its missing the stock number value like in the database table that ties the item to the stock qty. So when you re-save the item it is injecting that default value.

So its something wrong with your import. If in stock is set, make sure there is a value as well. I forget the column name but their should be a column for the stock qty itself.

I believe its something along those lines. Can you attach the csv you are using? or a sample line.

Comment: Actually I am loading a CSV into an array, do some modifications and then use the FOSS `AvS_FastSimpleImport` module. I will try to add a sample line of this array to the question. Not sure if the problem is only related to this module -- did you do any standard-test-import and it worked with the stock?

Comment: Yeah Ive had this issue and it was because of manually copying tables from one db to another and it came down to that. Could be that or one of the indecies of the stock tables. Try it with specific stock values and see what happens.